# Why I can get all Messages when Message HTTP REST API is disabled?

Tags: commercetools

I recently work with Commercetools platform and I have a question.

I disabled Message Settings in Admin Center you can see it here:

[image]

But when I execute Query:

```
client.executeBlocking(MessageQuery.of()).getResults();
```

I get all my Messages.

Why is it happens? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. Turning off the messages will not remove existing messages. However, no new messages will be published.

Does that make sense?

Best Regards
Brian

Comment: I mean, if messages are disabled, it means that MessageQuery should not pulling a Messages?